# Looking for inside mongodb collection diacritic insensitive

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code inside my nodejs, that recieve a word.:

```
exports.findProductsByWords = async (req, res) => {
  let searchWords = req.body.searchWord; // Replace with your array of words
  console.log("searchWords", searchWords);

  try {
    const producto = await Producto.find({
      title: { $regex: searchWords, $options: "i" },
    }).collation({ locale: "es", strength: 2 });
    /* .populate({
        path: "author",
        select: "nombre direccion telefono email imagesAvatar",
      }); */
    console.log("el producto :" + producto);
    res.status(200).json({ prodAll: producto });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Hubo un Error");
  }
};
```

i would like to recieve from my collection Producto, all the products, that have the word 'arnés', although i writte in my search field 'arnés' or 'arnes'.

I did think that with collation i achieve, but not works.
In my database the word is allways whit arnés, but maybe the user would type 'arnes' and i would like to work.

Some idea?
I use mongoose: 7.5.0 in my nodejs backend.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set up a [$text](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) search index. Log into your database with mongosh or connect using compass and run:

```
db.products.createIndex({title: "text"}, {default_language:"spanish"}); 
// I assume your collection is called products
```

This will allow you to do a text search on the `title` property of each `product` and it will not matter whether the value passed is 'arnés' or 'arnes' because by default, the `$diacriticSensitive` boolean option is set to false.

> $diacriticSensitive boolean. Optional. A boolean flag to enable or disable diacritic sensitive search against version 3 text indexes. Defaults to false; i.e. the search defers to the diacritic insensitivity of the text index.

Now you can run your `Model.find()` like so:

```
const producto = await Producto.find({
   $text: {
      $search: "arnes Monica léo"
   }
});

// Returns
[
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92771"), title: 'Arnes'},
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92772"), title: 'arnes'},
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92773"), title: 'Arnés'},
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92774"), title: 'arnés'},
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92775"), title: 'Leo'},
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92776"), title: 'leo'},
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92777"), title: 'Léo'},
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92778"), title: 'léo'},
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92779"), title: 'Monica'},
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92780"), title: 'monica'},
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92781"), title: 'Mónica'},
   {_id: new ObjectId("64ff81dd507561a33ce92782"), title: 'mónica'}
]
```

If you want the query to be case sensitive then you will need to pass in the `$caseSensitive` option and set it to `true` like so:

```
const producto = await Producto.find({
   $text: {
      $search: "arnes Monica léo",
      $caseSensitive: true
   }
});
```